# Bootstrap 3.0.0 - what is replacement of bootstrap-responsive.css?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After I upgraded my application to bootstrap 3.0.0 from bootstrap 2.3.2 it doesn't layout very well, and it seems to be because of missing bootstrap-responsive.css in this latest release. Does anyone knows the workaround here? There doesn't seems to be anything in the bootstrap doc (at least I couldn't locate it)

Comment: http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3.0 there is not needed resposive css. Quoting [migration guide](http://bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide):

> "Mobile first" is a responsive Web design practice that prioritizes
>   consideration of smart phones and mobile devices when creating Web
>   pages. For Bootstrap 3, there is no longer a separate
>   bootstrap-responsive.css file. All responsive features are now
>   compiled into a single core bootstrap.css file.

Comment: So if I am still based on the span grid classes, and 3.0 doesn't have the classes, what should I do?
It looks quite awful

Comment: @BujancaMihai Look on this article: http://blog.jetstrap.com/2013/08/bootstrap-3-grids-explained/

Comment: Thanks, it's a really useful link. To be honest, the new grid system doesn't really cheer me up, as I don't really understand why would you need 4 classes, each for a size, as they could have just continued to use one single class with the media queries needed.

Comment: I felt the same way, honestly, but then realized the power you get by having multiple layouts easily laid out in a grid you can manage. this is especially helpful with form layout. If you want to use only one single class, I recommend simply find and replacing the appropriate span# with col-xs-#. Also note that offset only works for col-sm-# and larger. Also, bootstrap is smart enough to know that if you set `col-xs-12` and `col-sm-8` for the same element, this implies 8 columns in the grid for `md` and `lg`; you don't have to explicitly set `col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8`