# Replace navigation with bootstrap navbar in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Just for the sake of testing I'm using the twentythirteen theme. I followed the steps in [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/how-to-integrate-bootstrap-navbar-into-wordpress-theme/) but the toggle in mobile view is broken. Here's what I did:

I went to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and checked:

- **Navbar** under LESS files
- **collapse** under jQuery plugins because of what it says [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) (Plugin dependency)

Downloaded the file.

Unzipped the file and

- placed `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` in
  *twentythirteen/css/*
- Placed `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` in *twentythirteen/css/*
- Placed [this file](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php) in *twentythirteen* as per tutorial suggestion

Changed `<nav>` contents `header.php` from this:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h3>
        <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div><!-- #navbar -->
```

to this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --> 
    <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> 
    </div> 
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --> 
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li> 
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a> 
                <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                    <?php /* Primary navigation */
                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                            'menu' => 'main_navigation',
                            'depth' => 2,
                            'container' => false,
                            'menu_class' => 'navbar',
                            //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                            'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                        );
                    ?>
                </ul> 
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and added the following to the beginning of `functions.php`:

```
/* Bootstrap navigation setup */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpt_setup' );
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wpt_setup' ) ):
        function wpt_setup() {  
            register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary navigation', 'wptuts' ) );
        } endif;


function wpt_register_js() {
    wp_register_script('jquery.bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap.min');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_register_js' );

function wpt_register_css() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_css' );

require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');
```

Loaded the page in xampp and the navigation is broken :(

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to change something in the code?

**EDIT:** Don't know if I'm doing something right but I changed the `menu` and `menu class` values (main_navigation is the name I gave to my menu in the dashboard). It still doesn't work, tough.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu' => 'main_navigation',
  'depth' => 2,
  'container' => false,
  'menu_class' => 'navbar',
  //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
  'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
```

See the problem in action: [broken navbar](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13823768/broken%20navbar.mp4)

Comment: First you probably need responsive css from bootstrap

Comment: Can you post what you changed in `header.php` and `funcitons.php`?  I don't know what the original files are supposed to have.  Also, what does 'broken' mean?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @afuzzyllama edited the original post. Broken as in, the toggle function is broken.

Comment: @Rastko What responsive css? Can you link me to it? thx

Comment: In some distributions of bootstrap there is separated responsive.css

Comment: If you have trouble figuring the classes and setup, maybe checkout some already implemented bootstrap wordpress theme like :

http://320press.com/wpbs/

Comment: @Rastko Just did a search, can't be responsive.css because I'm using 3.0. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479389/bootstrap-3-0-0-what-is-replacement-of-bootstrap-responsive-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot, you've included your javascript files out of order.  You should include the jQuery library before the bootstrap library.

Comment: Thx. Gonna have a look right now right now. What I don't understand, tough is why? Shouldn't people use the default html and js from the bootstrap example page in order for the menu to work?

Comment: I'd have to look at the event bound to the navigation click to see what was going on.  What that on click does should give you an idea of what structure it is looking for.

Comment: Don't know if this is what you meant but the chrome console log says: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined bootstrap.min.js:11
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: Do you have jQuery included? Can you run something like `$("body")` from the console and get a defined response?

Comment: I have http://pastebin.com/9u4JDwLn in functions.php  and http://pastebin.com/gNKndjX0 in the head tag of the page source. How do I run $("body") from the console?

Comment: You need to include jquery before bootstrap

Comment: Bingo! Can you edit your post so that I can accept this as an answer?