# where is the bootstrap-responsive.css file?

Tags: bootstrap-sass

I am using bootstrap sass:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

but where is the boostrap-responsive.css file? I'm trying to add the classes row-fluid to make a layout as shown in this link, but no classes are being picked up.

jsfiddle.net/SxcqH/52/

Comment: Just by following the instructions on the page you linked, all of the bootstrap responsive classes work for me... you installed both necessary gems, added the two bootstrap @import statements, and update the application.js?

Comment: but do you know which file .row-fluid is in exactly? and the rest of the fluid layout related styles? within bootstrap sass, because I don't inlcude some files.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no bootstrap-responsive.css within Bootstrap 3.x, the .css is separated for each of the elements within the /assets/stylesheets/bootstrap folder, called and imported by the _bootstrap.scss.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3.x has no "boostrap-responsive.css" file anymore.
All responsive classes are now being compiled into a single css file.
*Bootstrap for Sass* is currently based on Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.4.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479389/bootstrap-3-0-0-what-is-replacement-of-bootstrap-responsive-css).